# gettext PO files syntax

Tags: syntax, gettext

Can I make different translation in different places?

For example:

```
#: orders/models.py:49 templates/products_list.html:54
msgid "Order"
msgstr "Заказать"
```

But I want anything like this (it's not working)

```
#: orders/models.py:49
msgid "Order"
msgstr "Заказ"
templates/products_list.html:54
msgid "Order"
msgstr "Заказать"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [context parameter of the `pgettext` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Contexts.html) to select different translations. In the po file this would look as follows:

```
#: orders/models.py:49
msgctxt models
msgid "Order"
msgstr "Заказ"

templates/products_list.html:54
msgctxt products
msgid "Order"
msgstr "Заказать"
```